# Customer Community Plus- FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Document with ID: is already linked with the entity with ID error only in Experience Cloud

Tags: apex, contentdocument

I am inserting into Contentdocument like this

```
        ContentVersion cVersion = new ContentVersion();
        cVersion.PathOnClient = firstName +'.pdf';
        cVersion.Title= firstName +'.pdf';
        cVersion.VersionData =pg.getContentaspdf();
        Insert cVersion;
        Id conDocument = [SELECT ContentDocumentId  FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:cVersion.Id].ContentDocumentId;
       
        ContentDocumentLink cDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDocument;
        cDocLink.LinkedEntityId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        cDocLink.ShareType = 'I';
        cDocLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
        Insert cDocLink;
```

and I am getting this error

```
Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Document with ID: is already linked with the entity with ID
```

But when I replace

```
 cDocLink.LinkedEntityId = UserInfo.getUserId();
```

with any other valid Account, Contact Id's like

```
 cDocLink.LinkedEntityId = '0012F00000pSz7gQAC'; 
// Just hard coding the id to explain here
```

Things are fine. Only issue is with , If I insert through user id.

I am just directly calling this from my LWC and not through any trigger.

This is hapening in Experience cloud site only. In normal lightning app things are fine.

For community we are using this license -- Customer Community Plus and I feel chatter is enabled for the profile. I checked that in workbuilder.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the community license type and if you have disabled chatter for the community users.

Comment: @DavidCheng , I hvave edited and updated the post.